# mod_rewrite - URL with subdirectory

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change this URL:
**example.com/stickit/note.php?note=1**
to this:
**example.com/stickit/note/1**

I have tried to do it this way, but all I get is a 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^stickit/note/(.*)$ /stickit/note.php?note=$1 [L]
```

Funnily enough, this works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^note/(.*)$ /stickit/note.php?note=$1 [L]
```

It changes **example.com/stickit/note.php?note=1**
to : **example.com/note/1**

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^note/(.*)$ /stickit/note/$1 [L]
```

I also wrote a blog article that may help you better understand Apache rewrites...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/apache-domain-neutral-redirect

Always made sure you pay attention to your Apache access and error logs, they will help give you some insight in to what is going on.